# Cleaning text for multiple files in Python

Tags: python, csv, text

I am working a script to clean up a .txt file, create a list, count frequencies of unique words, and output a .csv file with the frequencies. I would like to open multiple files and combine them to still output a single .csv file.

Would it be more efficient to write code that would combine the text across the .txt files first or to read/clean all the unique files and combine the lists/dictionaries afterwards? What would the syntax look like for the optimal scenario?

I have been trying to research it on my own but have very limited coding skills and can't seem to find an answer that fits my specific question. I appreciate any and all input. Thanks!

```
import re

filename = 'testtext.txt'
file = open(filename, 'rt')
text = file.read()
file.close()

import re
words = re.split(r'\W+', text)

words = [word.lower() for word in words]

import string
table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in words]

from collections import Counter

countlist = Counter(stripped)

import csv

w = csv.writer(open("testtext.csv", "w"))
for key, val in countlist.items():
    w.writerow([key, val])
```

Comment: You don't need an optimal scenario before you really understand why. Use any appropriate way which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the frequencies of words for multiple files and outputting it into one CSV file, you won't need to do much to your code, just add a loop in your code e.g.:

```
import re
import string
from collections import Counter
import csv

files = ['testtext.txt', 'testtext2.txt', 'testtext3']
stripped = []

for filename in files:
    file = open(filename, 'rt')
    text = file.read()
    file.close()

    words = re.split(r'\W+', text)

    words = [word.lower() for word in words]

    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    stripped += [w.translate(table) for w in words]  # concatenating parsed data

countlist = Counter(stripped)

w = csv.writer(open("testtext.csv", "w"))
for key, val in countlist.items():
    w.writerow([key, val])
```

I don't know if this is the most optimal way of doing it.
It will depend on factors like: how big are the files? and how many files do you want to parse? and how frequently do you want to parse `x` files of `y` size? etc etc.
When you have figured that out, you can start thinking of ways to optimize the process.

Comment: @SarahSteinhauer you're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer, if the question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

if you need calculate the frequency, it's better to combine the strings from multiple .txt files at first, to know the performance, you can write the datetime function at the begining and end of the processing.